# How to touch/press a button/View using AndroidViewClient?

Tags: android, view, androidviewclient

I have an app, for which i wanna run Monkeyrunner (using Android ViewClient)

I am trying to define my view as

```
Vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
vc.dump
touchProject = vc.findViewByIdorRaise('id/projectNewGallery')
touchProject.touch()
```

But I am getting **error** : ->`"com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.ViewNotFoundException: Couldn't find View with ID='id/projectNewGallery' in tree with root=ROOT"`

How can i set root ? like this ?

```
  touchProject = vc.findViewByIdorRaise('id/projectNewGallery','id/projectMain')
```

?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am trying to use culebra tool, But I am getting following error.

```
$ java -jar androidviewclient-2.3.16.jar culebra
ERROR: monkeyrunner was not found and Windows 7 does not support shebang in scripts.    Aborting.
```

I also tried this way (Non-Shebang OS -> Windows 7 )

```
$ /cygdrive/c/android-sdk/tools/monkeyrunner.bat -plugin /cygdrive/c/Android_Resources_Hassan/MonkeyRunner_KIneMaster/AndroidViewClient-master/AndroidViewClient/bin/androidviewclient-2.3.22.jar culebra myscript.py
Plugin file doesn't exist
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

-s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
-p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
-v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO, WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)
```

Ok i was able to run it Windows CMD :

```
C:\android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner -plugin C:\Android_Resources_Hassan\MonkeyRunner_KIneMaster\androidviewclient-2.3.24.jar test3_py.py
```

but I got following error again :

```
130619 14:41:15.725:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]    Script terminated due to an exception
130619 14:41:15.725:S [MainThread]  [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\android-sdk\tools\test3_py.py", line 71, in <module>
touchProject = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/projectNewGallery')
File "C:\Android_Resources_Hassan\MonkeyRunner_KIneMaster\AndroidViewClient- master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1919, in  findViewById
OrRaise raise ViewNotFoundException("ID", viewId, root)
com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.ViewNotFoundException: Couldn't find View with    ID='id/projectNewGallery' in tree with root=ROOT
```

my script file --------------------

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
'''
Copyright (C) 2012  Diego Torres Milano
Created on Feb 3, 2012

@author: diego
'''


import re
import sys
import os

# this must be imported before MonkeyRunner and MonkeyDevice,
# otherwise the import fails
try:
ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME = os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME']
except KeyError:
print >>sys.stderr, "%s: ERROR: ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME not set in environment" %    __file__
sys.exit(1)
sys.path.append(ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME + '/src')

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

#starting script
print "start"

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()


#device connected
print "connection started"

# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'com.example.app.myApp'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
activity = 'com.example.mainapp.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package + '/' + activity

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

#device set to sleep for 4 seconds 
print "wait for 4 seconds"

 # first screen shot event
 MonkeyRunner.sleep(4);


 vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
 vc.dump()
 root = vc.getRoot()

#touchProject = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('', root)
touchProject = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('projectNewGallery')
touchProject.touch()


# wait for screenshot to save
MonkeyRunner.sleep(2);


# Takes a screenshot
result1 = device.takeSnapshot()
        result1.writeToFile('/myPath/shot1.png','png')


# wait for 3 seconds
MonkeyRunner.sleep(3);
```

is ID same as defined in XML android:id="+id/newProjectGallery" ?

////////////////////// **AFTER adding vc.traverse()  in code**///////////////////

I am getting following error

```
130620 10:07:43.775:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]    Script terminated due to an exception
130620 10:07:43.775:S [MainThread]   [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\android-sdk\tools\test.py", line 71, in <module>
    ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).traverse(transform=ViewClient.TRAVERSE_CIT)
  File "C:\Android_Resources_Hassan\MonkeyRunner\AndroidViewClient-  master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1687, in traverse
   print >>stream, "%s%s" % (indent, s)
 LookupError: unknown encoding 'ms949'
```

Moreover I ran dump-simple.py code also. But I am getting again the same error :

```
130620 10:07:43.775:S [MainThread] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]   Script terminated due to an exception
130620 10:07:43.775:S [MainThread]   [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\android-sdk\tools\dump-simple.py", line 30, in <module>
  ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).traverse(transform=ViewClient.TRAVERSE_CIT)
File "C:\Android_Resources_Hassan\MonkeyRunner\AndroidViewClient-  master\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 1687, in traverse
print >>stream, "%s%s" % (indent, s)
LookupError: unknown encoding 'ms949'
```

what is causing it ?
Please help me ~

Thanks

Comment: There are some indentation problems in your code but I'm assuming they are due to copy/paste. Just add `vc.traverse()` after `vc.dump()` and the whole tree will be printed and you'll see the ID or uniqueIDs of your views.

Comment: I tried to use vc.traverse() after vc.dump(). I am getting error which I posted above

Comment: You may solve it changing the encoding at the beginning of the script. Google for this problem.

Comment: it works fine on MAC OS X , but windows still got this problem, Can't find that encoding solution on Google...

Comment: http://scripting.tistory.com/78 perhaps?

Comment: @dtmilano Which version I need to use if i want id of view and position (-x) option It gives alarm error for all except dump-verbose branch on github

Comment: @AbhijitShelar you may post a new question explaining your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of errors in your snippet (check this corrected version):

```
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno)
vc.dump()
touchProject = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/projectNewGallery')
touchProject.touch()
```

to simplify the process, you can just use [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) to generate the correct script template that you can, later on, adapt to your needs:
When the device screen contains the desired Views:

```
$ culebra -VC -o myscript.py
```

edit `myscript.py` to add the call to the `touch()` method and run

```
$ myscript.py
```

The use of verbose comments (`-C`) simplifies the identification of Views if IDs are not available.

## Update

1. You were almost there in your first example, I guess the problem should be fixed by my corrected snippet before. The code run, the only problem may be you are expecting IDs that are not there.
   Remember, there are no IDs if the back-end is UiAutomator, which is the default back-end for API >= 16.
2. The java runner expects `monkeyrunner` to be in the PATH.
3. It seems `/cygdrive/c/Android_Resources_Hassan/MonkeyRunner_KIneMaster/AndroidViewClient-master/AndroidViewClient/bin/androidviewclient-2.3.22.jar` does not exist. At least this is what `monkeyrunner` thinks. Perhaps you should use `\` in Windows paths.

Comment: How to use Culebra tool ? I am getting this error : /usr/bin/env: monkeyrunner: No such file or directory  ( I am using Windows system and able to run simple .py script using AndroidViewClient -> Starting an app/Activity and running example such as settings.py)

Comment: No. Please explain to me how can I run Culebra Tool ?  I couldn't figure it out.  you mentioned myscript.py above. Is it my python script file or just a random name ?

Comment: You should read https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki. `myscript.py` is just a placeholder name.

Comment: You may also try latest version (2.3.24), available in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-LQuHEMta7PVTZwTENTRjdwVVE&usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to run code, but still got error

Comment: You didn't pay attention to one of my updates: "Remember, there are no IDs if the back-end is UiAutomator, which is the default back-end for API >= 16", which I guess is what you are using.